# What does "a-" before a verb mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs, prefixes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The times they are a-changin'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/the-times-they-are-a-changin)
>   [The times are a-changing? Why a-?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/the-times-are-a-changing-why-a)

While listening to some Bob Dylan I've noticed how he sometimes uses the construction **a-verb** (e.g. *The Times, They Are A-Changin'*) and wondered how to interpret it.

Where does this **a-** come from? What does it mean? When can it be used?

Comment: Have a look at the extensive discussion here http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=283120&highlight=a-changin