# Why is there an 'A' in phrase 'Times are a changing'?

Tags: idioms, indefinite-articles

I am not sure if the phrase `Times are a changing` is used exclusively within or related to [the Bob Dylan song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7qQ6_RV4VQ) but the A is bugging the hell out of me every time I see it.  Why is there an [`indefinite article`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Indefinite_article) in front of an adjective which is not followed by a noun?

Comment: Because it's not an indefinite article. It's "Times are a **-** changing"; and [here's the *a*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-) (first entry).

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[The times they are a-changin'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4604)* — or *[The times are a-changing? Why a-?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5248)* ; also see *[What does the “a’ ” in “a’blowing” signify](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84842)* and *[What we've gelost — why doesn't English use the prefix “ge-”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22700)*

Comment: It's a dialectal prefix that goes on participles in some dialects. It's not an article.

Answer (score 3):

This is a dialect relic of the oldest form of the progressive construction, going back to OE: *BE* + the preposition *an*/*on* + a noun or a gerund.

The preposition was gradually reduced to a neutral vowel /ə/, spelled {a}, and the gerund eventually collapsed into the *-ing* form.

The same construction with nouns gave rise to many of the modern postposed adjectives beginning *a-*: *asleep* (*on sleep*), *awake* (*on wake*), *alive* (*on life*).