# What are adjectives that begin with 'a' called in grammar?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

I mean adjectives like: *ablaze*, *afloat*, *alive*, *ashore*, ...

I did a quick Google search and found that they are called **a adjectives**. But I do remember that I came across a different denomination in a grammar book some time ago, but I have since forgotten that word.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I believe they are simply called: "prepositional phrases" (e.g., *asleep* comes from the Old English PP “on sleep”). I don't know if *that* is the answer you are looking for, if it is, someone can expand and submit it.

Comment: Thx for your edit & for adding 'alive' @Mari-LouA. But I think I came across a different word than your suggestion.

Comment: Closely related: [What is the history of adding the a- prefix to form words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/what-is-the-history-of-adding-the-a-prefix-to-form-words)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Interesting & informative but still not very helpful!

Comment: Consider the possibility that your memory might be playing tricks on you, you *think* there is a specific grammatical term for this type of construction. What you are remembering is the actual construction itself, the realization that the "a" is used as a prefix, a throwback to the days when it was a preposition.

Comment: Related: **1.** [The times they are a-changin'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/the-times-they-are-a-changin) **2.** [The times are a-changing? Why a-?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/the-times-are-a-changing-why-a) **3.** [What does the “a’ ” in “a’blowing” signify？](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84842/what-does-the-a-in-a-blowing-signify?lq=1) **4.** [progressive forms: participle or gerund?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148670/progressive-forms-participle-or-gerund)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Got to go and find da book; gosh, don't even remember what grammar book was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxford ALD refers to them as predicative adjectives usually occurring after copulative verbs such as Be, Seem, Get, Become, Look, etc. Also:http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm

Comment: Found the book -- it refers to them as predicative adjectives too.Thank you for your help.

Comment: From the link: *The most common of the so-called a- adjectives are *ablaze*, *afloat*, *afraid*, *aghast*, *alert*, *alike*, *alive*, *(etc.). These adjectives will primarily show up as predicate adjectives (i.e., they come after a linking verb).*  Not all adjectives that begin with an "a" are predicative. Not all predicative adjectives are "a-adjectives".