# What does the “a’ ” in “a’blowing” signify？

Tags: meaning

Quotation from [*A History of the Cries of London: Ancient and Modern*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/37114)

> Oh, dearly do I love “Old Cries,”
>      Your “Lilies all *a’blowing*!”
>     Your blossoms blue, still wet wih dew,
>      “Sweet Violets all *a’growing*!”

[image]

Comment: I don't have my *OED* in front of me now, but I think this is a ME construction *a* + gerund which derives from the OE 'dative infinitive' with *on*. It's more often spelt *a-*. It lingered fairly late in dialect -- e.g. "don't look at him while I'm a-telling it" from *Martin Chuzzlewit* -- but it's probably no longer productive except in self-consciously "folkish" or archaic contexts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The times they are a-changin'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/the-times-they-are-a-changin)

Comment: @RegDwighт  I think it *is* a duplicate; but I think (I'm not sure) the answer there is in important respects wrong.

Comment: @tchrist  Barrie England has stepped up to the plate; can these questions/answers be merged?

Comment: Another related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/what-is-the-story-behind-a-prefix-suffix

Answer (score 6):

Entries in the OED suggest that in both words the *a-* prefix is derived ultimately from the preposition *on*, which is used, as in your examples, before the *-ing* forms of verbs to give the sense of ‘engaged in’. The OED has, for example, this citation from 1883:

> Now let us run out and look at the flowers and the trees all agrowing
>   and ablowing.

One of the meanings of *blow*, which it clearly has here, is ‘to burst into flower; to blossom, bloom’.

The OED’s earliest record of *agrowing* is dated 1605. *Ablowing* is found in Old English, but with the medical sense of ‘swelling’ or ‘distension’.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia says [the **a-** prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_prefixes) is used to form *a predicative adjective with **progressive aspect***.

OED gives a dozen or more origins/meanings for the **a-** prefix, but I must admit I can't see any there that really correspond to OP's examples except #11, where it says *the force of the prefix is so little apparent, that the derivatives in a- hardly differ in sense* (in respect of, say, *rise/arise, wake/awake*).

So I think in OP's particular examples, the **a-** prefix either means *nothing at all* (effectively OED's take), or it can be seen as replicating/emphasising the *progressive aspect* of the verb (which is also being done by the **-ing** "suffix" anyway).

The apostrophe in OP's case is arbitrary (you could replace it with a hyphen, or nothing at all).

Comment: Look at senses 12 and 13 of OED **a-** prep 1.  Or see the [chatlog](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6384192#6384192) from earlier today.

Comment: I wonder if we’re looking at the same OED. Definition 11 in the first entry for the prefix in the online OED <http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8#eid2874815> has ‘Expressing action, with a verbal noun or gerund taken actively. Now arch. and regional’. 11a has ‘After "be" (or occasionally another verb expressing state) and before a verbal noun: engaged in (some activity).’

Comment: @Barrie: They won't be the same - my OED is a "bent" electronic copy from a few years back, but obviously you have access to latest edition (I can't follow your link because I'm an unexpectedly impecunious pensioner who can't afford the subscription). But really, how much could OED's understanding of this prefix change in 2-3 decades?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I, too, am an imp. pen., if not an unex. one, but if you have a UK public library card you can get a free subscription.

Comment: @Barrie: I didn't know that! I just assumed "Institutional subscribers" meant people coat-tailing whatever school/college they worked at. I'm ashamed to say I didn't get a new library card when I moved a few years ago, but my lodger is always telling me I should. I'll follow that one up, thanks.

Comment: ...incidentally, looking more closely at **a-** prefix in *my* OED, it gives different "origins" for 14 out of 15 entries. The only one where it doesn't is #11 as quoted from above. I still think it's relatively meaningless in OP's two examples, where it doesn't really add anything that's not already implicit in the **-ing** verb form. And whereas *afloat, atremble*, for example, seem unexceptional to me even without **-ing**, I can't easily persuade myself that *ablow, agrow* are "reasonable words".