# a-verb-ing construct (e.g. a-hopping)

Tags: verbs, history, construction, verb-construction

I sometimes here casual phrases in English like *a hipping and a hopping (a hippin and a hoppin)*.

How exactly does this fit into English grammar and what is the history of the construct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The times they are a-changin'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/the-times-they-are-a-changin)

Comment: Look around a bit and let us know what you found. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the *Oxford English Dictionary* (e.g. through your local library), this is covered under [a, *prep.<sup>1</sup>*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8). The OED considers it to be a variant of the preposition *on*. It includes both a number of senses where it introduces a regular noun — quotations include "Those fat and fair Objects that make their mouths run a-water so" from 1664 and "He was here a Sunday" from 1996 — and a number of senses where it introduces a gerund, with quotations going as far back as the 1200s.

Grammar-wise, you can mostly think of it as an explicit participle marker; whereas "going" can be either a gerund ("Going there is fun!") or a participle ("We're going there!"), "a-going" can only be a participle ("We're a-going there!").

Per the OED, it can also sometimes have a passive sense (e.g. "abuilding" meaning "being built"); but then, the bare present participle can also sometimes have a passive sense (called the "passival"), so I guess that's still in line with its being an explicit participle marker of sorts.